# Is it legal in XML to mix text and tags?

Tags: xml

Is the following an acceptable XML structure?

```
<Root>
    <Child ID="1" Name="test">some inner text
        <SecondChild ID="1" Name="test1">some text</SecondChild>
        <SecondChild ID="2" Name="test2">some text 2</SecondChild>
    </Child>
</Root>
```

I want to insert innertext() as well as child nodes to the `<Child/>` node. Is this legal within XML?

Comment: Please clearly state whats your problem..

Comment: There is no problem, I am just quering the correct structure of XML when it is constructed. Is it acceptable to have innertext on the same level as the child elements?

Comment: This is a perfectly valid question which should have been answered by pointing to the [mixed content](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#sec-mixed-content) section of the XML specifications. Voting to reopen.

Comment: It is legal but not "idiomatic", i.e., that's not how proficient XML authors like to do things. There are probably good reasons for that dispreference, such as certain things being easier if you don't. Although I couldn't say what theese reasons are, I'd suggest you adhere to the conventions unless you have really good, concrete reasons to go your own way. That's good practice in general, actually...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally, you don't have to insert some raw text in addition of childs elements in your  tag ...

What are you trying to do please ?

anyway you can verify it here : http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_validator.asp

There is apparently no errors in your document so far.

Answer (score 1):

It is legal, but not recommended, because:

- you break the semantic of the objects that are represented by the XML content
- you cannot defined a XSD in order to validate your XML files
- the code to parse the elements containing both text and tags is more complex to write and test (you have to handle the inner space and newline characters)

**What can be done:**

- if you get to this situation because you need to add text in your element, embed the text part into a new child of the element or as an attribute to the tag
- if you get to this situation because you need to add new information to your element, you may either :

  - move the text part of your element to a child of this element, and add the new items as new children
  - add the new items as attributes to the existing tag